# Create an index-by table and populate with rows from emp, then loop over and print them

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Create an index-by table and populate with rows from emp, then loop over and print them.

hi can anyone understand this question and give me the suggestions to solve this please..

Comment: thanks anyways i dint understand how to start this.

Comment: start by reading Oracle documentation/tutorial. that's best suggestion I can give.

Comment: i think we have to use the below one to solve this

Comment: CREATE INDEX  emp_ename ON emp(ename)
   TABLESPACE users
   COMPRESS 1;

Comment: is it right??? or wrong??

Comment: Yes it is. See answer.

Comment: is it same as in the case of varray creation..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A collection is an ordered group of elements having the same data type
>   which can be accessed though subscript/index. Oracle PL/SQL supports
>   three different types of collection
>
> ```
> Index-by tables or Associative array
>
> Nested table
>
> Variable-size array or Varray
> ```

Below is an example of how you can define a `Index-by table` and populate it with rows from `Emp` table and print them accordingly.

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c_emp is
      select name from emp;

   TYPE c_list IS TABLE of emp.name%type INDEX BY binary_integer;
   name_list c_list;
   counter integer :=0;
BEGIN
   FOR n IN c_emp LOOP
      counter := counter +1;
      name_list(counter)  := n.name;
      dbms_output.put_line('Employee('||counter|| '):'||name_list(counter));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

See [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm) as well as [PL/SQL - Collections](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_collections.htm) for more information on the same.

Comment: thanks mr.rahul u helped alot

Comment: i try to do tht but it needs 15 reputations

Comment: is it same as in the case of varray creation

Comment: My bad, I got confused with creating index on table and given a wrong answer. You are actually talking about collections in Oracle and Yes varray is also a collection type which stores fixed-size sequential collection of elements of the same type but creation is different than index-by table (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_arrays.htm). See edited answer again.